# Add new column based on subset of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df similar to this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'frequency': [3,5,7,8],
              'name': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
              'parent': [np.nan, 'a', 'a', 'b']})
```

which looks like this:

```
   frequency name parent
0          3    a    NaN
1          5    b      a
2          7    c      a
3          8    d      b
```

It is basically a tree structure and what I want is to sum the frequency of the children in a new column. It should look like this:

```
   frequency name parent  sum_of_children
0          3    a    NaN               12
1          5    b      a                8
2          7    c      a                0
3          8    d      b                0
```

What is the best way to do it? My idea is to get a subset of the df for each name where the current name == parent and then sum the frequency of this subset. Is this a good approach and how is it implemented best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["sum_of_children"] = [
    df.loc[df["parent"] == n, "frequency"].sum() for n in df["name"]
]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   frequency name parent  sum_of_children
0          3    a    NaN               12
1          5    b      a                8
2          7    c      a                0
3          8    d      b                0
```

---

EDIT:

To get *sum of children* we use list-comprehension. Iterating over column `"name"` we get all rows where column `"parent"` is equal of this name. Then we use `Series.sum()` to get the value (it will gracefully handle `NaN` values).

Comment: @jezrael Added :)

Comment: Superou., glad can support y